# Why set.discard doesn't throw an error when a set is passed to it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

My question is quite simple.

When I run

```
someSet = {1,2,3,4}
someSet.discard([5])
```

It gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File.py", line 2, in <module>
    someSet.discard([5])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Just like list, sets are also unhashable and can't be stored in a set.
So, I expect the following code to generate an error:

```
someSet = {1,2,3,4}
someSet.discard({5})
```

But to my surprise, it did not generate any error. Why is it so? Does this mean that I am getting an error for list as there something other than it being unhashable which gives rise to the error? If yes, then what is that thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [weird special case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.clear) where if you pass another set to `set.remove`, `set.discard`, or `x in set`, the set is silently converted to a frozenset.

> Note, the *elem* argument to the `__contains__()`, `remove()`, and `discard()` methods may be a set. To support searching for an equivalent frozenset, a temporary one is created from *elem*.

Comment: Thanks, it's my mistake that I didn't tried to search in the docs for this and I am sorry for this. I will accept the answer when the 6 min limit is over.